# Is there a way to change the return value with a TypeScript decorator?

Tags: typescript, methods, return, decorator

I'm trying to change the behavior of various methods. The behavior consists of checking if there is an value within the parameters sent and setting an property on the returned value from that method.

Example:

```js
function ParseDiscounts {
    return function (
        target: any,
        propertyKey: string,
        descriptor: PropertyDescriptor,
    ) {
        const originalMethod = descriptor.value;
        descriptor.value = async function (...args: any[]) {
            if(args[0].discounts !== undefined) {
                /**
                 *
                 * here is where supposed to add a property on the return
                 * something like resultToBeParsed.isDiscountApplied = true
                 *
                 * */
            }
            const result = await originalMethod.apply(this, args);
            return result;
        };
        return descriptor;
    };
}

class Order {
    @ParseDiscounts()
    createOrder(discountPayload) {
        /**
         * Do everything that it is supposed to do while only at the return of the function
         * the `isDiscountApplied = true` is added to the result through the decorator
         * */
        return resultToBeParsed
    }
}

const firstOrder = new Order()
const firstResult = firstOrder.createOrder({ otherProperties: 'blah, blah, blah', discounts: [1,2,3]})
// firstResult.isDiscountApplied = true

const secondOrder = new Order()
const secondResult = secondOrder.createOrder({ otherProperties: 'blah, blah, blah'})
// secondResult.isDiscountApplied = false
```

When there is any discount whithin discountPayload, I want the `resultToBeParsed` to be added a property `isDiscountApplied = false (e.g.)`

I know that I could do something like creating an `parsedResponse`whithin the decorator and assign the result whithin, but I also want to manipulate the method return cycle (I don't even know if it is possible).

I don't know if it is the best approach, really, if you guys know something better, I’d be more than happy to hear... I'm doing this way since there's a lot of place which I’ll use this.

Comment: It is not possible for decorators to change the types of their targets. However, you can always explicitly annotate them yourself.

Comment: i thought so... do you know any tool which i can easily achieve something like that?

Comment: Are you keeping the *type* the same but just changing the *value*?  Or are you changing the *type*?  It would be nice to see a [mre] here where you have something actually happening instead of "do everything it is supposed to do" and "Check if there is any discount inside the {discountPayload}" so any solution I propose is testable against a common example

Comment: Like, [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/N7o3PN) shows how one might use decorators to wrap methods to change the return *value* without changing the *type*.  If you need to change types then that's important info that should be in the question.

Comment: And [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NrXQ5W) is how one might tackle changing return types, but you have to abandon decorators to do it.  Let me know how you'd like to proceed here or if none of these meet your needs (mention @jcalz in a comment to notify me).  Good luck!